# Where to put method used in XML when it is infalted with layoutinflater?

Tags: android, android-activity, methods, android-alertdialog

I have 10 similar buttons in a layout (create_new.xml) which will be distinguished based on the tag attribute:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:tag="one"
    android:onClick="numberClicked" />
```

I would like to use the same defined method for all of them.

The problem: this is built with an AlertDialog:

```
private void openCreateDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View createNumbersView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_new, null);
    // more code
}
```

... and I don't know where to put this method (numberClicked)

I tried to write it simply in the activity but then it couldn't find the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `onClick` XML attribute (like, ever). Define an `OnClickListener` programmatically and assign it to each of your buttons using `setOnClickListener()`. You can do all that right inside your `openCreateDialog()` method.

```
View.OnClickListener buttonOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {  
          //insert contents from numberClicked() method here
    }
};

button1.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClickListener);
```

Comment: I understand. This is what I'm trying to avoid... +10 id setting in xml +10 findViewById +10 setOnClickListener, but what if I had 100 buttons? Is this possible at all what I asked?

Comment: Not without creating a ton of extra boilerplate. For instance, if you made a custom DialogFragment class rather than using AlertDialog.Builder, you could include your numberClicked() method inside it. The problem with your approach is that the onClick XML attribute only looks for methods that are found in Contexts where the XML layout is actually inflated. Since the AlertDialog.Builder inflates its own layout separate from the Activity it's housed in (and there's no way to define your own methods within the Builder), there's no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.